# PHP Error Warning: require_once On Wordpress 3.4.1

Tags: php, windows, wordpress, shared-hosting, plesk

I am using Reseller Club Multi domain Windows shared hosting on Plesk 10.
Getting following errors, i feel it's a server config issue, can you please suggest some solution

> Warning: require_once(D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\ladybirdwebhost.com/wp-load.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\ladybirdwebhost.com\wp-blog-header.php on line 12
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\ladybirdwebhost.com/wp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP5\pear;./includes;./pear') in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\ladybirdwebhost.com\wp-blog-header.php on line 12

Even when i try to post/add pictures in wordpress i get similar errors

> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Windows\Temp\php7DD1.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\httpdocs) in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\fitnessorganiser.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2505
>       79

Comment: Looks like your PHP doesn't have access to the Temp directory, which is where new file uploads are stored until they get moved elsewhere by PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this kb:
http://kb.parallels.com/en/432

Comment: If he's using shared hosting, it's very unlikely he'd be able to do any of this.